# Is it wrong to have a class which implement an interface and also implement an interface which extend the first interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I can't set a title for this question better, I really apologize if it is not clear.I try describe my question by showing some code:

I have an interface like:

```
public interface ITest
{
  int Age{get; set;}
}
```

and also another interface which extend the ITest like:

```
public interface ITest_2: ITest
{
  string Name{get; set;}
}
```

now I make an implementation like:

```
public class TestImplementation: ITest_2,ITest
{
  public int Age{get; set;}
  public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

as you know it is enough when I just implement ITest_2. Now my question is,is there any situation that we should implement like that? For example in microsoft class I see this like List, it is implementation of IList and ICollection while IList extends an ICollection.

Comment: I knew I'd seen this somewhere in BCL classes, so `List<>` is the one I took a look at, too.  However, while you can see those "redundant" interfaces in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1), they're not present in [the actual code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,36).